# Not getting input from sensor using timer

Tags: arduino-mega, timers

I wrote a code to move linear actuator and lights up and down using timer. But its not getting Sensor input please help me in this.

#include <avr/sleep.h>//this AVR library contains the methods that controls the sleep modes
#define interruptPin 2 //Pin we are going to use to wake up the Arduino

int uv1 = 7; //light
int uv2 = 8; // light
int mot1 = 5; //motion down
int mot2 = 6; // motion up
int buzz=39;
const int speaker = 27;
int led = 9;
int ledState = LOW;
int inputPin = 10;               // choose the input pin (for PIR sensor)
int pirState = 0;            // variable for reading the pin status, we start, assuming no motion detected
long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 2000;
long OnTime = 30000;
long SenseDel = 8000;           // milliseconds of on-time
long OffTime = 8000;
unsigned long timestart = 0;

const int ply = 23; // relay to reset the sound
const int stp = 35; //relay to puase sound
bool sound = false;

long time_taken = 0;
int start_delay = 3000;
int audio_time = 8000;
int audio_time1 = 8000;
int audio_time3 = 8000;
void setup()
{
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
pinMode(uv1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(uv2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(mot1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(mot2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);      // declare LED as output
pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);     // declare sensor as input
digitalWrite(mot1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(mot2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led, LOW);
pinMode(interruptPin,INPUT_PULLUP);//Set pin d2 to input using the buildin pullup resistor
Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(ply, OUTPUT);
pinMode(stp, OUTPUT);
pinMode(speaker, OUTPUT);

// TIMER 1 for interrupt frequency 300.0018750117188 Hz:
cli(); // stop interrupts
TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
TCNT1  = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
// set compare match register for 300.0018750117188 Hz increments
OCR1A = 53332; // = 16000000 / (1 * 300.0018750117188) - 1 (must be <65536)
// turn on CTC mode
TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
// Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 1 prescaler
TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (0 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
// enable timer compare interrupt
TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
sei(); // allow interrupts
digitalWrite(speaker,LOW);
audio_message();
delay(200);

}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{ //interrupt commands for TIMER 1 here
pirState = digitalRead(inputPin);
}

void loop()
{

unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
while ((pirState == HIGH) && (currentMillis-previousMillis >=SenseDel))

{
//previousMillis = currentMillis;
Serial.println("Motion detected!");
digitalWrite(mot2, LOW);
digitalWrite(mot1, LOW);
digitalWrite(uv1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(uv2, HIGH);
//delay(SenseDel);
//Go_To_Sleep();

}
// We only want to print on the output change, not state
//pirState = HIGH;

while ((pirState == LOW) && (currentMillis-previousMillis >= OnTime))
{

```
previousMillis = currentMillis;
Serial.println("Moving Down");
digitalWrite(mot2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(mot1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(uv1, LOW);
digitalWrite(uv2, LOW);
pirState = HIGH;
```

}

while ((pirState == LOW) && (currentMillis-previousMillis >=  OffTime))
{

```
//previousMillis = currentMillis;
Serial.println("Stay There!");
digitalWrite(mot2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(mot1, LOW);
digitalWrite(uv1, LOW);
digitalWrite(uv2, LOW);
pirState = HIGH;
```

}

while ((pirState == LOW) && (currentMillis-previousMillis >=  OnTime))
{

```
//previousMillis = currentMillis;
Serial.println("Moving Up!");
digitalWrite(mot2, LOW);
digitalWrite(mot1, LOW);   
digitalWrite(uv1, LOW);
digitalWrite(uv2, LOW);
tone(buzz,2000);
delay(1000);
noTone(buzz);
delay(1000);
 pirState = HIGH;
```

}
}

void Go_To_Sleep()
{
sleep_enable();//Enabling sleep mode
attachInterrupt(0, wakeUp, LOW);//attaching a interrupt to pin d2
set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);//Setting the sleep mode, in our case full sleep
sleep_cpu();//activating sleep mode
Serial.println("just woke up!");//next line of code executed after the interrupt
audio_message();
}

void wakeUp()
{
Serial.println("Interrrupt Fired");//Print message to serial monitor
sleep_disable();//Disable sleep mode
detachInterrupt(0); //Removes the interrupt from pin 2;
}

void stop_button()    // func to act as stop sound
{
digitalWrite(stp, LOW);
delay(200); //100
digitalWrite(stp, HIGH);
}

void play_button()  // // func to act as play sound
{
digitalWrite(ply, LOW);
delay(140);//100
digitalWrite(ply, HIGH);
}

void audio_message()
{
digitalWrite(speaker, HIGH);
play_button();
sound = true;
delay(100);
//digitalWrite(speaker, LOW);
Serial.println("Speaker On");
play_button();
//time_taken = millis();
delay(audio_time1);
delay(audio_time);
//delay(audio_time3);
//Do something.....
play_button();
stop_button();
sound = false;
digitalWrite(speaker, HIGH);
Serial.println("Speaker Closed");
delay(1000);
}

Comment: First, please format your code properly (standard Markdown rules apply). Secondly, what sensor isn't it receiving the input from? What hardware do you have, how is it wired up, and how do you expect it to behave?

Comment: reduce your code to only read the sensor and print its value ... your sketch has a lot of code that is unrelated to the sensor

Comment: `pirState` needs to be declared volatile